# Eloquent efficiency for composing links in a rest api

Tags: laravel, rest, eloquent

We are doing a learning exercise with Laravel 5.8 and Eloquent for developing a version of a REST api.

The database tables (company, contact & note) are rather simple in terms of their relationships:

```
company -> hasMany -> contacts
company -> hasOne -> note
```

The Model code looks like:

```php
class Company extends Model
{
    // ....

    public function contacts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contact::class);
    }

    public function note()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Note::class);
    }
}
```

To access each of these resources, the api is:

```
/api/companies
/api/notes
/api/contacts
```

We are wanting to return links to the foreign resources when `/api/companies` is hit. e.g.:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "trading_name": "Example Company",
            "_links": {
                "contacts": [
                    "http://localhost:8100/api/contacts/1",
                    "http://localhost:8100/api/contacts/2",
                    "http://localhost:8100/api/contacts/3"
                ],
                "notes": "http://localhost:8100/api/notes/1"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

We are using Laravel's `JsonResource` to format the response object.

The question is around the `_links`. For the links we use the following code:

```php
$contacts = $this->contacts->map(
    function($contact) {
        return route('contacts.show', [ 'contact' => $contact->id ]);
    }
);

$links['contacts'] = $contacts;
$note = $this->note;
if ($note != null) {
    $links['note'] = route('notes.show', [ 'note' => $note->id ]);
}
$links['self'] = route('companies.show', [ 'company' => $this->id ]);
```

We only get the `id` field to generate the `_links` array.

Is the above the way these links are generated in Laravel/Eloquent?

Comment: What you're doing is fine. There is no specific way you have to generate those links in Laravel or Eloquent. If it works, stick with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You described the most reasonable way to generate the links, although your code can be slightly optimized by removing some unnecessary assignments:

```
$links['contacts'] = $this->contacts->map(function ($contact) {
    return route('contacts.show', [ 'contact' => $contact->id ]);
});

if ($this->note !== null) {
    $links['note'] = route('notes.show', [ 'note' => $this->note->id ]);
}

$links['self'] = route('companies.show', [ 'company' => $this->id ]);
```

If, however, the `id` is everything you need of your `contacts` and `note`, you can only load this information from your database. Be careful to also load foreign keys required to map these foreign objects back to their parent though:

```
$company = Company::query()
    ->with([
        'contacts' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(['id', 'company_id']);
        },
        'note' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(['id', 'company_id']);
        },
    ])
    ->find($companyId);
```

---

An absolutely dirty way, and I'm not even sure it is much more efficient, would be to build a *route template* and replace the `id` part directly in SQL. But I don't recommend it and I only write it for the sake of demonstration:

```
$companyRoute = route('companies.show', ['company' => 999999]);
$contactRoute = route('contacts.show', ['contact' => 999999]);
$noteRoute    = route('notes.show', ['note' => 999999]);

$company = Company::query()
    ->with([
        'contacts' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(['id', 'company_id', \DB::raw("REPLACE(?, '999999', id) as link")])
                ->addBinding($contactRoute, 'select');
        },
        'note' => function ($query) {
            $query->select(['id', 'company_id', \DB::raw("REPLACE(?, '999999', id) as link")])
                ->addBinding($noteRoute, 'select');
        },
    ])
    ->select([
        '*',
        \DB::raw("REPLACE(?, '999999', id) as link"),
    ])
    ->addBinding($companyRoute, 'select')
    ->find($companyId);
```

**The last snippet is untested and NOT meant to be used.**

Answer (score 2):

There is no "right way" to do this, but for me what you're doing is good.

Nevertheless, there is a specification called [jsonapi](https://jsonapi.org/) that describes how to share links.

There is a [Laravel package](https://github.com/cloudcreativity/laravel-json-api)  for this.